# Use Native Base Toast To Show Error From Redux Action

Tags: react-native, react-redux, toast, native-base

I'm using NativeBase in a React Native app. I'm trying to show a Toast component based on an error that is set in an redux action because it happens via a call to the API.

It will show now, but currently I get the warning message:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I'm not sure how I could bind this or what I could do to solve the warning.

**Render Method**

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderError()}
      {this.renderForm()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Render Error Method**

```js
renderError() {
  if (this.props.error.type === 'server') {
    return (
      Toast.show({
        text: this.props.error.message,
        buttonText: 'Okay',
        duration: 5000,
        type: 'danger'
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**Versions**

React Native: 0.55.4

Native Base: 2.4.5

**Edit:** Adding an example for clarity

I need to show a Toast based on the response from the server. For example, if the username and password don't match an account, I need to render the Toast.

**Solution:**

I ended up creating a ToastService:

```js
import { Toast } from 'native-base';

function showToast(message) {
  return (
    Toast.show({
      text: message,
      buttonText: 'Okay',
      duration: 5000,
      type: 'danger'
    })
  );
}

export default {
  showToast
};
```

and now in my action I can just call:

```js
ToastService.showToast(data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function and call this one outside. But make sure your app is wrap with the Root component of native-base. No need to return a component like you do. Calling this function gonna show the toastr and now you have the freedom to call from anywhere. But make sure Root component wrap your app.

import { Toast } from 'native-base';

```
export const toastr = {
  showToast: (message, duration = 2500) => {
    Toast.show({
      text: message,
      duration,
      position: 'bottom',
      textStyle: { textAlign: 'center' },
      buttonText: 'Okay',
    });
  },
};
```

Now inside your action you can call the toastr function

`toastr.showToast('Verication code send to your phone.');`

Or in redux actions

```
const signup = values => dispatch => {
  try {
    // your logic here


  } catch (error) {
    toastr.showToast(error.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Its throwing exception: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property '_root' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by using React Hooks.

```js
() => {
       useEffect(() => {
           if(error) {
               Toast.show({
                   text: this.props.error.message,
                   buttonText: 'Okay',
                   duration: 5000,
                   type: 'danger'
               })
            }
        })

        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderForm()}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check React Native Seed for this implementation
https://reactnativeseed.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Looking through their code, it looks like they are only validating the input from the form and showing the Toast based on that. I need to show the Toast based on a response from the API. For example, if the username and password don't match an account, I need to show the Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dwayne says above, you need to use useEffect so that Toast is called before the render cycle. You can wrap this is a component like so:

```
const ErrorToast: React.FC = () => {
    const {state} = useCollections();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(state.errored) {
            Toast.show({
                text: 'Oops. There has been an error',
                duration: 2000
            });
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

And then simply include it as `<ErrorToast />`